# Using decltype(auto) in C++ non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, decltype-auto

I am learning C++17 new feature `decltype(auto)` for non-type template parameter. I wrote a simple code snippet as following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<decltype(auto) arg>
struct Foo {};

int
main()
{
    constexpr int x = 42;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Foo<42>, Foo<x>>);
}
```

As I understand, `Foo<42>` should be the same type as `Foo<x>`.

However, The `static_assert` statement compiles with clang++, MSVC 19.27 but fails with GCC 10.2, MSVC 19.25.

My question is: Why do compilers behave differently? What does the Standard say about this?

Link to Compiler Explorer:

clang++ https://godbolt.org/z/66M695

gcc https://godbolt.org/z/3v5Mhd

MSVC 19.25 https://godbolt.org/z/qP6v89

MSVC 19.27 https://godbolt.org/z/14aK5Y

Comment: Why not just auto? (There are many valid reasons, but it is possible you don't even know it would work)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: I am learning the new feature so I want to try things to double check my understanding.

Comment: <https://godbolt.org/z/cWvKaj>: gcc seems to think `Foo<x>`'s template argument is of type `const int` (So `Foo<(const int) 42>`), whereas `Foo<42>` is just `int`

Comment: @Artyer: Thanks. Now I think gcc may be correct because type of x is ```const int```. However, C++ Standard is full of weird cases so I can not be so sure. :)

Answer (score 16):

It's all in the rules describing how `decltype` works.

> **[dcl.type.simple]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4) For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is
> defined as follows:
>
> - if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a structured binding ([dcl.struct.bind]), `decltype(e)` is the referenced type as given in
>   the specification of the structured binding declaration;
> - otherwise, if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(e)` is the type of the
>   entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if e names a set
>   of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - otherwise, if e is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> - otherwise, if e is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> - otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.

When using `decltype(auto)`, `e` is the expression that is used as an initializer for our object (`arg`). In the OP, this expression is `x`. It's an unparenthesized id-expression, so `decltype(x)` would be the type of the entity named by `x`. That type is `int const`, because a `constexpr` specifier implies `const`.

> **[dcl.constexpr]**
>
> [9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.constexpr#9) A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares
> the object as `const`. Such an object shall have literal type and shall
> be initialized. In any `constexpr` variable declaration, the
> full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression.

So here's a cute modification to your code sample that makes GCC accept it.

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Foo<42>, Foo<+x>>);
```

Why is that? It's because `+x` is no longer an id-expression. It's a plain old prvalue expression of type `int`, having the same value as `x`. So that's what `decltype(auto)` deduces, an `int`.

All in all, the compilers that rejected your code are acting correctly. And I guess it goes to show you that using `decltype(auto)` for a non-type template parameter should come with a short disclaimer.

Comment: I'm agree with you but there is a point that isn't clear to me: where, in the C++17 standard, is stated that `Foo<x>` and `Foo<y>` are different types when `x` and `y` are the same value of different types (as `Foo<42>` and `Foo<42L>`)? In "Type Equivalence" (14.4) I read (1.4) "their corresponding non-type template arguments of integral or enumeration type have identical values". But "identical values" require also identical types? Also regarding the constness?

Comment: I think the top level `const` doesn't apply here for non-type template parameters. At least, that's my reading of the text. I added an answer with that interpretation.

Comment: @max66 - "identical values" doesn't require const qualifiers. It's a property of types, not values. But on another note, the CWG issue list is full of template related shenanigans, so I can't really speak with too much authority on anything but the most obvious cases.

Comment: @max66 The text you cited doesn't work exactly. Identical values doesn't necessarily imply identical types. Types need to work as well, otherwise `Foo<49>` and `Foo<'1'>` would be the same. (I think).

Comment: @cigien - Exactly: `Foo<49>` and `Foo<'1'>` are identical types?  Both g++ and clang++ say "no". But which rules say they are different?

Comment: @max66 Placeholder type deduction rules. One gives `int` and the other gives `char`. Their values being same doesn't help, they're still not equivalent.

Comment: @cigen - Sure. Buth which rule say that `Foo<(int)49>` is different from `Foo<(char)49>`? I mean: which rule say that two templates, with a template non-type parameter, are different when the non-type parameters are equals in value but different in types?

Comment: @max66 Well if there was `template<int> void f();` and `template<char> void f();` those would get called respectively, regardless of the values used in the calls.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica Thanks for your answer.  What do you think are use cases in which decltype(auto) for non-type template parameters really shine?

Comment: @mibu - Well, if you are hosting a social event for C++ developers and need a sort of "pub quiz" topic. I honestly haven't seen a situation where you'd `decltype` deduction semantics for templates.

Comment: @cigien No, `template<int> void f();` and `template<char> void f();` are different templates, so they violate https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.type#1.1

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica For template-ids `Foo<42>` and `Foo<x>`, their template-names all refer to the entity that was introduced by declaration `template<decltype(auto) arg> struct Foo {};`. So they do not violate anything in this [list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.type#1). In other words, (1.1) and (1.3) in that list all be satisfied. Hence `Foo<42>` and  `Foo<x>` would be the same class(According to [Type equivalence] section). However they should be different type in the intuitive, maybe a defect in that list?

Comment: @jackX - Those specializations don't have the same **type** for the non-type parameter. That's the whole point. **[temp.type]/1** assumes the placeholder type is deduced the same when determining type equivalence.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The requirements in that list do not talk about the specialization. I think the key is, whether the rule **their template-names**, operator-function-ids, or literal-operator-ids refer to **the same template** is first satisfied. in this example, it means that whether these `template-names` refer to the same template? This is my argument, there is no any rule in the standard that says these names (`Foo`) refer to `template<int const arg> struct Foo`, `template<int  arg> struct Foo` respectively. IMHO, according to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#5

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica These names `Foo` should refer to the unique declaration, namely `template<decltype(auto) arg> struct Foo {};` which is the entity we declared.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica No offence. I just say how  can I determine whether two specializations(namely two template-ids) are equivalence according to [temp.type].  At least, there is no rule in that list be violated. So the two specialization would be equivalence type. However in my intuitive, I agree with your answers. IMHO,  I think there is a vague in type equivalence. And frankly, I voted your answers.

Comment: @cigien According to **A class template shall not have the same name as any other template, class, function, variable, enumeration, enumerator, namespace, or type in the same scope**, that means it cannot exist two different class template with the same name in the same scope. how could exist `template<int> struct Foo` and `template<int const> struct Foo` in the same scope (deduced by template-arguments)?

Answer (score 5):

In C++17, I think `GCC` is wrong due to the following rules:
[temp.type#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.type#1)

> Two template-ids refer to the same class, function, or variable if
>
> > 1.1 their **template-names**, operator-function-ids, or literal-operator-ids refer to **the same template** and
> > [...]
> > 1.3 their corresponding non-type template arguments of integral or enumeration type **have identical values**

Formally, a name is used to refer to the entity
[basic.concept#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#5)

> Every name that denotes an entity is introduced by a declaration.

So, whether `Foo<42>` or `Foo<x>`, their template-names all refer to the entity `template<decltype(auto) arg> struct Foo {};` we declared.  So the bullet `1.1` is first satisfied. Obviously, in this example, the corresponding template-arguments have the identical values, namely `42`. At least, according to what the c++17 standard says, they are the equivalence type. Hence `GCC` is wrong.  In addition, [GCC 7.5](https://godbolt.org/z/5Ws318) agrees these types are equivalence.

---

However, something is changed in the latest draft. It introduces a new wording "template-argument-equivalent".
[temp.type#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type#1)

> Two template-ids are the same if
>
> > 1.1 their template-names, operator-function-ids, or literal-operator-ids refer to the same template, and
> > 1.2 ...
> > 1.3 their corresponding non-type template-arguments are template-argument-equivalent (see below) **after conversion to the type of the template-parameter**

And
[template-argument-equivalent](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type#2)

> Two values are template-argument-equivalent if they are of **the same type** and
>
> > they are of integral type and their values are the same

As said in other answers, the deduced type for `Foo<42>` is `int`. Instead, the deduced type for `Foo<x>` is `int const`. Although their deduced types are different, However, such a rule should be obeyed:

> The top-level cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter are ignored when determining its type.

Hence `after conversion to the type of the template-parameter`, these two values are of the same type, so they are template-argument-equivalent. So, talking this example under the c++20 standard, `GCC` is still wrong.

Comment: Yes, I think this all looks correct. It should be a defect report I feel, the c++20 behavior seems correct :)

Comment: @cigien  After making some efforts, I found this [issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/3386) that made the wording be modified.

Comment: @cigien / jack X: I just found this interesting Q&A (I missed it in October). This answer seems reasonable, but so does [StoryTeller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64416537/4573247) (as well as your own cigien). Is this simply underspecified in the standard (such that both answers are "correct" interpretations, in a sense), or is one answer actually more correct than the other ones? I've read through all three several times and I can't decide myself :)

Comment: @dfrib  I gave a link in this answers that indicates the different behaviors between GCC7.5  and GCC(higher version), they gave the different result. That's sufficient to evidence that GCC follows the corresponding rule that modified in different draft.

Comment: @dfrib Yeah, it's a tricky one. Not sure if it's underspecified, or just poorly worded though :p I do like jack X's argument re the change in gcc's behavior, it does seem to be in response to wording changes. But I wouldn't count that as conclusive at all.

Comment: @cigien / jack X: thanks guys, I'm also favouring this answer if I have to choose one, but I agree the wording is vague, at best, here.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a gcc bug, and the `static_assert` should pass.

According to [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#1):

> If the type of a template-parameter contains a placeholder type, the deduced parameter type is determined from the type of the template-argument by placeholder type deduction. ...

*Placeholder type deduction* in this context mean the type of the parameter is deduced as if deduced by these invented declarations:

```
decltype(auto) t = 42; // for Foo<42> : int
decltype(auto) t = x;  // for Foo<x> : int const
```

And then, according to [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#4):

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> ...
>
> (4.6) a type that contains a placeholder type.
>
> **The top-level cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter are ignored when determining its type.**

Since the top-level qualifiers are ignored when determining the type according to the invented declarations, both `Foo<42>` and `Foo<x>` should have the same type, and the `static_assert` should pass.

Comment: Mmm... it's the cv-qualifiers on the parameter, not the argument. So if I parse it correctly, something like `const auto` is described here... but then again, the `const` doesn't change things normally, so why bother mentioning it. Aiee

Comment: Also, you cite the latest draft, not C++17. The closer to C++17 draft is here https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#4

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes, the expressions passed as arguments to the template do have qualifiers, but for deducing the type of the parameter I think those qualifiers are dropped.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Oh, true, OP explicitly says 17. Thanks for the link, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @cigien - Intriguing... but you linked the C++20 standard... but I don't find it in the C++17 standard... maybe a "defect" in the C++17 standard that is corrected in C++20?

Comment: I beg to differ. It says the qualifiers on the parameter are ignored when determining its type, not the argument. If I parse it correctly, it means a `const auto arg` won't be const qualified by virtue of its own const. I'm not sure it applies to a const brought forth by the argument.

Comment: @max66 I've changed the links/texts to the c++17 standard. The wording is moved around a bit, but still essentially there.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Hmm, that makes sense for `template<const auto arg>`, but then I would expect that `template<decltype(auto) const arg>` would be fine (just by ignoring the const), but it's not. Maybe that's just the constraint on `decltype(auto)` not being allowed additional qualifiers.

Comment: @cigien - yes... I was reading the wrong section; sorry. Interesting. I'm trying to understand what exactly mean (English isn't my native language and this sort of documents aren't exactly trivial) but I suspect you're right.

Comment: @cigien - The bad part is that they don't propose examples to show point 5 at work.

Comment: @cigien - Yes, `decltype(auto)` must be the only type specifier, so it doesn't even stumble upon this. For what it's worth, GCC agrees with my interpretation as far as `const auto` goes https://godbolt.org/z/r4G5jo.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I'm going to take that with a grain of salt, gcc seems happy to compile even [this](https://godbolt.org/z/8jP315) :p so I don't have much confidence it's doing the right/wrong thing here. Maybe that's worth a question in it's own right :)

Comment: @cigien - Sure, sure, but Clang agrees with me about `const auto arg` too. So I'm tempted to stay with my conclusion.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Absolutely. And I can't see why my answer is necessarily wrong, so I'm going to leave mine up too :) I'm tempted to stay with my conclusion because it *feels* like the assert should pass :p Certainly a lovely sunday afternoon puzzle :)

Comment: I'm not sure the people on the CWG mailing list will agree it's a lovely day if this issue is raised :P

Comment: @cigien The form `template<decltype(auto) const arg>` should be ill-formed due to this [rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct#5)